# I can't import my own modules in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Well, i tried to research and do it by myself but i only get more frustrated.

I have some cogs where i define very useful functions, but i want to have it in another place, not next to my commands.

If i try the thing i want to do in not-bot folder it works perfectly, but when i try to do the same in the bot folder this happens:

[My module import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqDyB.png)

```
Extension 'cog.anime' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
 File "C:\RoboTito\cog\anime.py", line 14, in <module>
  import functions.functions as func

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\RoboTito\main_bot.py", line 33, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f'cog.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Actually i have a tree like this:

Cog in "RoboTito/cog/anime.py"
Module in "RoboTito/cog/functions/functions.py"

I looked for old questions but nothing solves my problem. What can i do?

Comment: Can i see your code?

Comment: Change your import to `import cog.functions.functions as func`

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs because of the system of importing cog files. Let me explain, In your "main.py" file, I believe you have something like: `await client.load_extension("cogs.anime")`. In this case, all the modules that are imported in your anime.py file are actually imported by your main.py file. So, you need to import your module as if you were in your main.py file.

```
import cog.functions.functions as function
```

Hope that helps!